# SwiftUI - How can I select multiple rows in List with Sections

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I can't get multi row select to work when using a section list in SwiftUI. And when I select a row from the ordinary list view it renders the section list again.

I have tried changing the id for the list but to no avail, and I have tried to implement my own 'onTapGesture' but again the section list renders every time a tap gesture is recognized and scrolls to the top.

Can someone explain why this happens please?

Code to repro:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExerciseList: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    var categories: [ExerciseCategory] = []
}

struct ExerciseCategory: Identifiable, Hashable{
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var exercises: [Exercise] = []
}

struct Exercise: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let instructions: String
}

extension Exercise: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

struct SelectableList: View {
    @State var items = [
        Exercise(id: "1", name: "Ab Wheel", category: "Core", instructions: ""),
        Exercise(id: "2", name: "Aerobics", category: "Core", instructions: ""),
        Exercise(id: "3", name: "Arnold Press", category: "Shoulders", instructions: ""),
        Exercise(id: "4", name: "Around the World", category: "Full Body", instructions: ""),
        Exercise(id: "5", name: "Back Extension", category: "Back", instructions: ""),
        Exercise(id: "6", name: "Ball Slams", category: "Core", instructions: ""),
        Exercise(id: "7", name: "Crunch", category: "Core", instructions: ""),
    ]
    @State var selectedItem = Set<Exercise>()
    
    func categoriseExercises(exercises: [Exercise]) -> [ExerciseCategory] {
        var exercisesList = ExerciseList()
        var categorisedExercises = [String:[Exercise]]()
        for exercise in exercises{
            let exerciseCategory = exercise.category
            if categorisedExercises.keys.contains(exerciseCategory){
                categorisedExercises[exerciseCategory]?.append(exercise)
            }else{
                categorisedExercises[exerciseCategory] = [Exercise]()
                categorisedExercises[exerciseCategory]?.append(exercise)
            }
        }
        for category in categorisedExercises{
            let exerciseCategory = ExerciseCategory(name: category.key, exercises: category.value)
            exercisesList.categories.append(exerciseCategory)
        }
        return exercisesList.categories
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                List(categoriseExercises(exercises: items)) { section in
                    Section(header: Text(section.name)){
                        ForEach(section.exercises){ exercise in
                            Text(exercise.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItem){exercise in
                    Text(exercise.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Selectable List")
            .toolbar{
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews1: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SelectableList()
    }
}
```

Screenshots of one row selected, then section list renders again after second row selected:

[image: first screenshot]
[image: second screenshot]

Comment: Unrelated, but why is `Exercise` a class and conforms to `ObservableObject`? There is nothing being `@Published`. And the `required init` and the `CodingKeys` are redundant, you get both for free when adopting `Codable`. And as the class conforms to `Identifiable` why  `items.exercises, id: \.self`? Carelessly specifying `\.self` is very bad practice. You can omit the `id` parameter if the object is `Identifiable`.

Comment: Thank you for educating me on this - I haven't worked much with SwiftUI and have made the following changes: changed class to struct and removed Observable and the init and coding keys -- this still works.

When I remove the id: \.self from the list it no longer allows me to select the rows in Edit mode, I tried with id: \.id from the object but still no luck.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `Hashable` conformance either.

Comment: The `Hashable` conformance is needed for specifying the selectedItems?

Comment: What is your ` ReadExerciseData()`. Please make sure this is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb I have edited the post now. Apologies it just returns a list of Exercises.

Comment: I don't care if it returns turtles... However, it is still not building. Your `@State var items` init is incorrect. You need to start a new project, and put in just enough code to it to build and run, (or produce the same error if you are asking about an error in the future).

Comment: I have provided the minimal reproducible example now. I copied it into a new project and made sure it is all in one file for you so it is as easy as possible to reproduce with no errors. :)